# standard C float to custom floating point representation using 32-bit integer and bit-wise operators?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, floating, ieee

I'm trying to write a small program to convert a C float to a 12-bit floating point representation using a 32-bit integer and bit-wise operators.

The order goes: [unused (bits 31 - 12)] [sign (bit 11)] [exp (bits 10 - 6)] [frac (bits 5 through 0)]

```
[ ..., ..., ...] [] [][][][][] [][][][][][]
```

I'm only using the 12 L.S.B. for this representation.

For example,

using IEEE standard, the float 7.375 in binary is: 111.011

In scientific notation: 1.11011x2^2

bias = 2^(e-1)-1 = 15

E = 2

exp = E + bias = 17 = 10001

So I would want to store floating point representation in an integer as follows:

```
[... unused (bits 31 - 12 set to 0) ...]-[0]-[1][0][0][0][1]-[1][1][0][1][1][0]
```

I can do the conversion by hand, but I'm trying to accomplish this with bit-wise operations. I think where I'm stuck is, how would I accomplish the alleged shifting of the decimal point in the program in order to get frac portion of the representation? Also, how would I know the value of E?

Comment: Did you look up the documentation of IEEE `float`s? You may realize this by dissecting the `float` through a `union` with a `struct` of bitfields. However, this is implementation-defined behavior, see Annex J.3.9 of the standard.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to do this without union and a struct of bit-fields. I'm just trying to figure out how to get the frac and E portions of the float. To know E when doing this by hand, I have to shift the decimal to 1 place less than the M.S.B. If I shift a whole floating point number using bit-wise operations, will that have the same effect as shifting the decimal point?

Comment: Please take a good C book or even the standard and look up the chapter on expressions. You will find that bitwise shift and logical operators work only on integers. Why don't you want to use `union` and `struct`?